# Firebase functions/firestore not working and catch returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would just like to access my Firestore Database from within my Firebase Functions. I have tried to follow all the documentation and other stack overflow questions but still it is not working. Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const arrUsers = querySnapshot.map(element => element.data());
      return response.send(arrUsers);
    }).catch((error) => {
      // It is coming in here, and this below just returns '{}'
      response.send(error);
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method of a `CollectionReference` returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html) which "contains zero or more [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) objects representing the results of a query. The documents can be accessed as an array via the `docs` property or enumerated using the `forEach()` method".

Therefore you should do as follows, calling `map()` on `querySnapshot.docs`:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      const arrUsers = querySnapshot.docs.map(element => element.data());
      //return response.send(arrUsers);  //You don't need to use return for an HTTPS Cloud Function
      response.send(arrUsers);   //Just use response.send()
    }).catch(error => {
      //response.send(error);
      response.status(500).send(error)   //use status(500) here
    });
});
```

---

Note the changes to the code for returning the response and handling the error. I would suggest that you watch this official Firebase video on HTTPS Cloud Functions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA, it's a must!

Comment: I highly recommend this documentation when working with cloud functions. Great examples: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/index.html

Comment: Good answer! On `querySnapshot.docs.map(...` I keep making this mistake myself, since `QuerySnapshot` *does* implement `forEach()`, but *does not* implement `map()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the important thing I missed was the `querySnapshot.DOCS` part. Also thank you for the extra links to learn some more! Stuff like this is always useful